# Spring oauth2 slow performance

Tags: spring, performance, oauth-2.0

I have been trying out the `oauth2 library/framework` for `Spring`.

Tried it out for different `grant_types` and for example the client_credentials call to the oauth/token endpoints takes around 0.5 seconds with in-memory representation. While connected to a `mysql` database it takes around 3 seconds.

Is it supposed to be this slow?

Comment: I have the same problem... why is it so slowly? have you found out a good solution?

Comment: I'm digging into this presently. I'll be posting updates to the github issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/943